# Prevent multiple JS injections through MITM proxy to a single page

Tags: javascript, proxy, code-injection, reverse-proxy, mitmproxy

I am using MITM proxy to inject javascript code to traffic passing through the proxy. For now I am checking content-type of header to  be text/html, The problem I am facing is that on a single page there are multiple resources which have content-type as text/html so my javascript code is getting injected multiple times to the page.

How can I prevent this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Actually the question could be more HTTP specific, I know that I can filter content using the regex and inline scripts. But I am particularly interested in knowing what exactly should I look for in the request so that I can prevent this situation.

Answer (score 1):

MITM proxy supports regex [filter expressions](https://mitmproxy.org/doc/features/filters.html) to restrict the flows that you interact with. You can filter against specific parts of the request/request, such as the request URL or response headers.

You should set a filter that matches only the resource you want to alter.

For example, `~bs Page \d` matches against the response body and `~u http:\/\/mysite\.com\/resource\..+` matches the request URL.

Hit `i` in the mitmproxy app to enter a filter expression.

See [this blog post](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/01/how-to-use-mitmproxy-to-read-and-modify-https-traffic-of-your-phone/#Capture-and-alter-HTTP-and-HTTPS-requests-and-responses) and the [filter expression docs](https://mitmproxy.org/doc/features/filters.html) for more detail.

Comment: Hey @joews Thanks ! Actually the question could be more HTTP specific, I know that I can filter content using the regex and inline scripts. But I am particularly interested in knowing what exactly should I look for in the request so that I can prevent this situation. Added this to original question as a comment so that its more clear.